# I want to display text which file choose by user using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i used this below css

```
.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 999px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}
```

for my html

```
<div class=" btn btn-primary fileContainer">
   <div class="input-group">
      <i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-inverse"></i> Attachment
      <input type="file" ngf-select ngf-multiple="true" 
      ng-model="noteListData.files" name="files">
      </i>
   </div>
</div>
```

using this css i am not able to see that text .
help me out.
i want to display button as well as text also.

thank you

Comment: What text exactly can't you see?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out should be the attribute "opacity" instead of "filter". Try to set the "opacity" to 1.

Comment: By the way, I personally recommend this useful jQuery plugin: 
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo

Comment: I tried to copy your code and paste to a new html file, after i set the opacity to 1, it did work. Is it because you have set the font-size to 999px and it's over huge which makes you can barely see it?

Comment: can you please upload plunker or jsfiddle for that?